# Gh-pages not updating after deployment

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

Hi got an email yesterday when I ran npm run deploy that it ran into an error. The site is still up and working but none of the changes I commited are implemented. How do I go about syncing the ghpages and recent commits?

Tried rerunning npm run deploy on other laptop
Tried clearing ghpages cache in node modules then reran npm run deploy
Tried clearing browser cache
If I can't find a solution, might try deleting the repo and rebuilding the ghpages with a fresh repo.

This is what the email said:

reponame pages build and deployment: Some jobs were not successful
View workflow run
build
pages build and deployment / build
Failed in 0 seconds

annotations for pages build and deployment / build 1
report-build-status
pages build and deployment / report-build-status
Failed in 0 seconds

annotations for pages build and deployment / report-build-status 1
deploy
pages build and deployment / deploy
Skipped

Answer (score 1):

Ok in case this helps anyone else, turns out if you go to the gh-pages branch on github, there is either a green check mark or a red x mark that'll indicate to see if all the checks have passed. if they haven't then it wont update.

I clicked on the x and clicked on one of the errors which asked me if I wanted to re-run all the jobs, after doing so it fixed my issue. I'm not sure what the cause of the issue was but will update this answer if i figure it out